# floating divs borders not overlapping

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting create the following using HTML and CSS only.

- Each rectangle is either `50px` by `100px` and `100px` by `50px`.
- The RGB are `#ffffff`, `#cccccc`, `#999999`, `#666666`, `#333333`, order does not
  matter.
- The border is `1px` in color `#000000`.
- Place the product at the center of the page.

What I have so far

```
<section id="main">
    <div id="container">
        <div class="horizontal" id="box1">1</div>
        <div class="vertical" id="box2">2</div>
        <div class="vertical" id="box3">3</div>
        <div class="horizontal" id="box4">4</div>
    </div>    
</section>
```

CSS

```
* {
    margin:0px auto;        
}    
#main {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin-top:20%;     
}    
#container {
    background-color:#ff0000;
    height:153px;
    max-width:154px;  
}    
.horizontal {
    border:1px solid #000000;
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}    
.vertical {
    border:1px solid #000000;
    width:50px;
    height:100px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}    
#box1 {
    float:left;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}    
#box2 {
    float:right;
    background-color:#cccccc;
    clear:right;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
#box3 {
    float:left;
    background-color:#999999;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    clear:left;     
}
#box4 {    
    background-color:#666666;
    float:left;    
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;    
}
```

My issue lies within making this a exact square and the borders overlapping so they are only `1px`. also when I zoom out the bottom div is falling outside of the container.

Anyone wanna give this a shot?

*** Like this ***

```
___________________________________
|                       |         |
|                       |         |
|                       |         |
|-----------------------|         |
|       |               |         |
|       |               |         |
|       |               |         |
|       |               |         |
|       |               |         |
|       |               |         |
|       |_______________|_________|
|       |                         |
|       |                         |
|       |                         |
-----------------------------------
```

Comment: Can you provide a sketch perhaps of what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your borders push it out. Set the border to the container and leave the height and width at 150px, as it should be with rectangles of 100x50 in the layout you posted. Cleaned up the code.

[**JSFiddle demonstration.**](http://jsfiddle.net/v8uR7/)

```
* {
    margin:0px auto;
}

#main {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin-top:20%;
}

#container {
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background-color:#ff0000;
    height:150px;
    width:150px;
}

.horizontal {
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
}

.vertical {
    width:50px;
    height:100px;
}

#box1 {
    background-color:#ffffff
}

#box2 {
    background-color:#cccccc;
}

#box3 {
    background-color:#999999;
}

#box4 {
    background-color:#666666
}

#box1, #box3 {
    float: left;
}

#box2, #box4 {
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: awesome thats what i was looking for great help dude!

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it the way you want to because borders add pixels to the dimensions.

The closest thing you could do is remove one of the sides of each rectangle that otherwise would have double, [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/cyd4M/), but the container still has to be `153px` by `153px` because you have the border each side and one in between two elements

Using negative margins do the same thing as the above fix, but it is still impossible to get it 150x150 pixels using that method

Using `outline` instead you can get close, but you can't remove part of an outline [so it's not perfect](http://jsfiddle.net/cyd4M/1/)

This leaves you with the following options (in addition to the ones linked above) to have a perfectly 150x150 total box:

- [Don't have a border at all](http://jsfiddle.net/cyd4M/2/)
- [Make the inner rectangles smaller](http://jsfiddle.net/cyd4M/3/)

If you only  need a border around the outside then do as RDrazard said and apply the border to `#container`

Answer (score 0):

I did this and it worked:

html

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="div1">1</div>
    <div id="div2">2</div>
    <div id="div3">3</div>
    <div id="div4">4</div>    
</div>
```

css:

```
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#container {
    border: 1px dotted green;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    margin: 30px auto;
    background: red;
}

#div1 {
    background: #fff;
    float: left;
    width: 60%;
    height: 30%;
}

#div2 {
    background: #333;
    float: right;
    width: 40%;
    height: 70%;
}

#div3 {
    background: #555;
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
    height: 70%;
}

#div4 {
    background: #999;
    float: right;
    width: 60%;
    height: 30%;
}
```

Follow fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/637R9/

Comment: I don't believe these are the dimensions the OP requested

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/ku9bf/1/

Use negative margins, ex:

```
#box3 { margin-top: -1px; }
```

and reduce the max-width of the container by 1px.

Comment: That's not 150px by 150px

Answer (score -2):

the div falling out of the container is expected behavior because you are making a floating div. when the size of the screen grows the div is bound to be squeeze out of the container.